# InstructGPT - I want to understand the loss function of Reward Model

Tags: loss-function

I have recently read the paper Trainging language models to follow instructions with human feedback which suggests 'InstructGPT'.

There are 3 steps in InstructGPT models, and the second step is reward model.

The paper introduces the **loss function of** **Reward model**.
And this is that loss function.

[image]

All I want to know is **necessity of '-1/ (kC2)'**.

I know E_(x,yw,yl)~D [log(sigma(r(x,yw) - r(x,yl)))] represents the **expected value**, so I thought divided by -1/ (kC2) is already done.

Is there anything wrong in my thinking?

Answer (score 0):

we take negative log of sigma(chosen_answer_score - reject_answer_score), and then we take average of it from the batch size, and we calculate the loss for all pairs in the dataset. Base on the math, the loss is awalys positive, the reward model converge when the loss approches to 0 and diverge then loss approch infinite. Remeber we want chosen_answer_score - reject_answer_score>0.

Answer (score 0):

I think the your understanding "E_(x,yw,yl)~D [log(sigma(r(x,yw) - r(x,yl)))] represents the expected value" is not approprite.

"loss" means you want to minimize this value. In rewarding model, you want the score of chosen is much bigger than the rejected which means you want  r(x,yw) - r(x,yl) as big as much. This is contrative to the loss target, so it should add minus in the formula.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the term divided in the expected value is |D|.

[Reformulation of RM loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyB3m.png)

$loss(\theta)=$$-\frac{1}{\binom{k}{2}}$$E_{(x,y_w,y_l)\sim D}{[\Sigma_{i=1}^k\Sigma_{j=1}^{k}log(\sigma(r_\theta(x,y_{i})-r_\theta(x,y_{j})))]}$

$= -\frac{1}{\binom{k}{2}\times |D|} {{\Sigma_{z=1}^{|D|}}{[\Sigma_{i=1}^k\Sigma_{j=1}^{k}log(\sigma (r_\theta(x_z,y_{i})-r_\theta(x_z,y_{j})))]}}$

, where $i \neq j$ and  $r_\theta(x,y_{i})>r_\theta(x,y_{j})$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).